# Azure web app deployment through cicd pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-webapi, cicd, msbuild-task

I have created CI pipeline and using MS build for building project as .deploy.cmd file is required by release pipeline for deployment.

I am getting error in CI pipeline in processing MS Build task. Error is:

> MSB1008: Only one project cab be specified.

There is no space in project path. Although my solution name has space.

Comment: Looks like you are targeting multiple projects in a task that only allows a single project to be targeted, or you are using improper syntax to target multiple.  Are you using yml files to set up your pipeline?  Seeing that, or even an img of the UI pipeline might provide us some clarity.

Comment: Only one project can be specified. That’s an MSBuild error.
You might be passing multiple command on the same line so MSBuild.exe
thinks you are passing SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe as an parameter, which it unable to understand

Comment: Have you followed the above process?